# Setup routing in nested virtualization cluster on vagrant / hyper-v / libvirt

Tags: routing, hyper-v, libvirt, vagrant

I'm trying to setup a specific VMs cluster using vagrant on my local notebook. 
I have a Win10 Pro with HyperV as a host. Unfortunately I cannot change it thus I want to create a Linux VM on HyperV (I called it 'nested') with nested virtualization enabled. Then on 'nested' Linux I want to create several VMs using KVM/libvirt. For simplicity in an example code there is only one ('guest').

The assumption is to make a minimal setup on Windows Host and to provision everything by Vagrant. But in fact it's not so easy because HyperV provider does not allow to setup a static IP in both public and private interfaces.

The goal is to create a private network (e.g. 10.75.10.0/24) and to assign each VM a static IP address and allow to see each other. I partially achieved that. My VMs can ping each other except the nested one ('guest1'<->'guest2', 'guest'<->Host, Host<->Nested). guest<->nested don't see each other in both directions.

Requirements:
1. Win10 with HyperV enabled
2. User needs to be in HyperV admin group

I created an internal switch in Host using PowerShell script (Adm):

```
New-VMSwitch –SwitchName “NAT-Switch” –SwitchType Internal –Verbose
Get-NetAdapter
#put the proper index in the next line
New-NetIPAddress –IPAddress 10.75.0.1 -PrefixLength 24 -InterfaceIndex 16 –Verbose
New-NetNat –Name NATNetwork –InternalIPInterfaceAddressPrefix 10.75.0.0/24 –Verbose
Get-VM | Get-VMNetworkAdapter | Connect-VMNetworkAdapter –SwitchName “NAT-Switch”
```

ipconfig:

```
Ethernet adapter vEthernet (NAT-Switch):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #5
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : XXXX
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : XXXX
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.75.10.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

This is my project structure:

```
./nested
./nested/Vagrantfile
./provision.sh
./Vagrantfile
```

cat Vagrantfile

```
$bridge_script = <<EOF
    ifconfig eth0 10.75.10.10 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
    route add default gw 10.75.10.1
EOF

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.vm.box = "generic/ubuntu1804"
    config.vm.define "nested"
    config.vm.hostname = "nested"
    config.vm.provider "hyperv" do |hv|
        hv.cpus = "2"
        hv.memory = "2048"
        hv.maxmemory = "2048"
        hv.enable_virtualization_extensions = true
        hv.differencing_disk = true
    end

    config.vm.network "public_network", :bridge => "NAT-Switch", auto_config: false
    config.vm.provision :"shell", run: "always", inline: $bridge_script
    config.vm.provision :file, source: "nested", destination: "~/"
    config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "provision.sh"
    config.vm.provision :shell, inline: "sudo -i -u vagrant bash -c 'cd ~vagrant/nested; vagrant up --provider=libvirt'"

end
```

cat provision.sh

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y bridge-utils qemu-kvm virtinst libvirt-bin qemu-utils qemu ebtables dnsmasq vagrant vagrant-libvirt
usermod -aG libvirt-qemu,libvirt vagrant
systemctl enable libvirt-bin
systemctl start libvirt-bin
vagrant plugin install vagrant-libvirt
vagrant plugin list
```

cat nested/Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
        config.vm.box = "generic/ubuntu1604"
        config.vm.define "guest"
        config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "10.75.10.11", netmask: "24"
        config.vm.hostname = "guest"

        config.vm.provider :libvirt do |libvirt|
                libvirt.uri = 'qemu+unix:///system'
                libvirt.cpus = "1"
                libvirt.memory = "1024"
        end
end
```

After running:

```
vagrant --provider=hyperv
```

I get the following result:

nested VM:

vagrant@nested:~$ ip addr

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:38:01:5c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.75.10.10/24 brd 10.75.10.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe38:15c/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:6f:8e:84 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:6f:8e:84 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: virbr1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:6c:f9:2f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.121.1/24 brd 192.168.121.255 scope global virbr1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: virbr1-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr1 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:6c:f9:2f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr1 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:bc:01:c9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: macvtap0@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 500
    link/ether 52:54:00:a7:eb:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

vagrant@nested:~$ route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.75.10.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.75.10.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.121.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr1
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

For VM1:

vagrant@guest:~$ ip addr

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:bc:01:c9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.121.45/24 brd 192.168.121.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:a7:eb:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.75.10.11/24 brd 10.75.10.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

vagrant@guest:~$ route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.121.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.75.10.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.121.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

I hope someone can recreate the state. I provided a 99% automated scripts.

The question is:
How can I improve this setup to make nested vm visable?
Manipulating with interface addressing and routing cause a long break for vagrant to up. Can I also improve that?
Is there a better way to setup network in nested vm?